# SP 2010 Outlook calendar sync: What is this specific setting?

Tags: calendar, outlook, settings

This is a calendar I created in SharePoint and I want users to sync it to their local Outlook clients. When you initially connect the calendar to Outlook there is a dialog that comes up with a "yes" or "advanced settings" - the image is showing the advanced settings. I am specifically interested in the one I circled in red in the screenshot. I can't find any documentation out there on this, and it seems like this is a setting i would NOT want to have checked... but why would it be checked by default and hidden in advanced settings?  So maybe I don't have a good understanding of the setting. **Anyone able to enlighten me on this?**

[image: Notice the red box.]

Answer (score 0):

With that setting checked, the SharePoint calendar that you connect to Outlook, will appear in your Outlook when you log into another computer.  This is preferred.

If you uncheck this option, and you go to another computer, that calendar will not appear in Outlook.